# Download .sql.gz file

Tags: php

I have file on my website transferred from other server.

Backup has .sql.gz format, when I download file via php code they do not work. Files are download but corrupted. I am on windows pc whereas its works on linux

Please help me out how can I make them work on windows too, I am using the following code:

```
$fileurl=$path."/mysql/03/mydb1.sql.bz2";

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Type: application/download");

header("Content-Description: Download SQL Export");                 

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.sql.bz2');

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileurl));

readfile($fileurl);
```

Comment: Multiple `Content-Type` headers may be your problem. Try using only `application/octet-stream`.  The file is probably downloaded correctly, but Windows doesn't know what to do with it after downloading.

Comment: is it sql.bz2, or sql.gz ? `filename=test.sql.bz2` // Backup has .sql.gz format ??

Comment: Removed only using application/octet-stream file downloaded but still not working.

Comment: Where exactly does Windows report corruption? Is it when you try to untar & decompress the file? Do you have utilities installed capable of handling .bz2 archives?

Comment: Yes when i try to decompress, i have winrar and also 7zip installed

Comment: Conflicting content descriptions doesn't look good either - maybe remove one.

Comment: It seems likely that this isn't PHP's fault. I assume you have already tried decompressing the original file on Windows without the PHP download process? And another easy check is to verify the `sha1sum` of the downloaded file. If its sha1 hash is the same as on Linux, it's the exact same file and you can be certain it's 7zip and not PHP.

Comment: It was header related issue i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to pass a file through PHP.

```
<?php

    // replacement function for mime type
    if (!function_exists('mime_content_type')){
        function mime_content_type($file){
            ob_start();
            system('/usr/bin/file -i -b "' . realpath($file). '"');
            $type = ob_get_clean();

            $parts = explode(';', $type);

            return trim($parts[0]);
        }
    }

    //
    $file_path = '/your/file/path/here.gz';

    //
    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate\n");
    header("Pragma: hack\n");
    header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H") + 2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"))) . " GMT\n");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

    header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($file_path) . "\n");

    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_path) . "\n");

    $file_name = pathinfo($file_path);

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name['basename'] . "\"\n");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    if ($fp=fopen($file_path, "r")){ 
        fpassthru($fp);
    }
?>
```